# Doctrine ConsoleRunner (integration with codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I was following [this tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#setting-up-the-commandline-tool) from doctrine on how to integrate it with codeigniter.

At certain point the tutorial requires me to create a cli-config.php file.

I did create it on my codeigniter root folder.

Inside that file i added the following code:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'index.php'; // <------- what should i add here?

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

I'm not sure what they mean with "your own project bootstrap". 
I assumed they were talking about the index.php that is the central part of codeginiter.

Through the command line and located at Codeigniter root folder (where i installed the composer) I did "php vendor/bin/doctrine" but i got this error.

```
<div id="container">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.</p><p>Filename: core/Loader.php</p><p>Line Number: 346</p>    </div>
```

I'm feeling lost. Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**
Everything seems to be okay with the way Doctrine was installed and loaded into my codeigniter application because I can access doctrine entityManager from the application.

I just don't know if I'm setting up the console application correctly by referencing my central application index.php from codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Doctrine console component with CI but with ZF1 instead. But I think configuration steps are the same.

1. require_once 'index.php' means that you should make framework initialization, including loading of configs, modules, routes, service (including database) etc. - all that you need in your client application.
2. initialize doctrine with settings from step 1.
3. configure commands
4. run console application

Code sample

```
$application->bootstrap('doctrine2');                                           

$configurationOptions = $application->getBootstrap()->getOptions();             
$emArr = $application->getBootstrap()->getResource('doctrine2');                
$em = $emArr['default'];                                                        

$symfonyPath = $configurationOptions['resources']['doctrine2']['lib_dir'];      
$symfonyPath .= '/Doctrine';                                                                                   

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', $symfonyPath);       
$classLoader->register();                                                                                      

$cli = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Application('Doctrine Command Line Interface', Doctrine\ORM\Version::VERSION); 

$helperSet = $cli->getHelperSet();                                                                             
$helperSet->set(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()), 'db');
$helperSet->set(new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em), 'em');
$cli->setHelperSet($helperSet);                                                                                

$cli->setCatchExceptions(true);                                                 
$cli->addCommands(array(                                                        
    // DBAL Commands                                                            
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\RunSqlCommand(),                   
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand(), 
    ...
));                                                                             
$cli->run();
```